# Array unique change value

Tags: php, arrays

if have an php array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    array('tree' => array('apple', 'pear', 'quantity' => 1)),
    array('house' => array('door', 'window', 'quantity' => 1)),
    array('house' => array('door', 'window')), 'quantity' => 1)),
);
```

What i want to achieve is that if there's an duplicate value the quantity gets increased and the duplicate value gets deleted.

Anyone a solution?

Comment: Can you make an example how it should look like?

Comment: could you explain a little more? you want `cal_your_function($arr)` return just two rows in this particular case? which row mast be deleted? 2nd? 3rd? any 2nd or 3rd? give us more info, more examples please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
        $res2 = array();
        foreach ($arr as $n) {
            $key = key($n);
            (!isset($res2[$key])) ? 
                $res2[$key] = $n[$key] : 
                $res2[$key]["quantity"] += $n[$key]["quantity"];
        }
        print_r($res2);
```

**UPDATE**

It should do the trick for the new requirements:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$key] = json_encode($value);// Transform to string to be able to use array_count_values
}

$res = array();
$repeated = array_count_values($new_array);
foreach ($repeated as $val => $c) {
    $key = array_search($val, $new_array);// It will find the first one.
    $res[$key] = $arr[$key];
    $res[$key]["quantity"] = $c;
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: @CorvanOostenbrugge what's the problem?

Comment: @CorvanOostenbrugge please check the update, I think it'll work

Answer (score 1):

You can start by taking a look at [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). Below is a sample code that can **get you started.** Since you have not fully described the output you expect, the code below only demonstrates what I could make out of it.

**Note**: I can see a lot of edge cases in the way you have your data structure. Like: What if the first array element has more than one entries? How would you combine it in such a case?

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array('tree' => array('apple', 'pear', 'quantity' => 1)),
    array('house' => array('door', 'window', 'quantity' => 1)),
    array('house' => array('door', 'window', 'quantity' => 1)),
);

$res = array_reduce($arr, function($state, $item){
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($state[$key])) {
            $state[$key]['quantity']++;
        } else {
            $state[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $state;
});

var_dump($res)
?>
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["tree"]=> array(3) {
      [0]=> string(5) "apple"
      [1]=> string(4) "pear"
      ["quantity"]=> int(1)
  }
  ["house"]=> array(3) {
      [0]=> string(4) "door"
      [1]=> string(6) "window"
      ["quantity"]=> int(2)
  }
}
```